# Can I create Shimmer container with other containers in it?

Tags: flutter, dart, shimmer

I am using [shimmer package](https://pub.dev/packages/shimmer) for creating a loading page. This is how it looks:

[image: Shimmer I created]

I want to create the shimmer boxes like this:

[image: Shimmer I want to create]

My code:

```
class _Shimmer extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Shimmer();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Shimmer.fromColors(
      baseColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
      highlightColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
      enabled: true,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 40),
            ...List.generate(
              10,
              (index) => const Column(
                children: [
                  _CardPlaceHolder(),
                  SizedBox(height: 16),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _CardPlaceHolder extends StatelessWidget {
  const _CardPlaceHolder({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 86,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

When I add another container as the main container's child, it doesn't shown. Is there a way to create this with the package or should I create a new shimmer widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picked this from the [Shimmer](https://pub.dev/packages/shimmer/example) package's [example](https://github.com/hnvn/flutter_shimmer/tree/master/example/lib) folder and modified it a little. You can replace your _CardPlaceHolder code with this

```
class ContentPlaceholder extends StatelessWidget {
  // final ContentLineType lineType;

  const ContentPlaceholder({
    Key? key,
    // required this.lineType,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 86,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
          color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.4),
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6.0),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 96.0,
                height: 72.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 12.0),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 100.0,
                      height: 10.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: 10.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                    ),
                    // if (lineType == ContentLineType.threeLines)
                    Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: 10.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```